Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
I am trying to swap tokens on ZKsync using uniswap v3 router address in ethersJS. But getting Error: invalid address or ENS name
here is my code
const swapRouterAddress = "0x99c56385daBCE3E81d8499d0b8d0257aBC07E8A3";
const swapRouterAbi = [
"function exactInputSingle((address,address,uint24,address,uint256,uint256,uint160)) 
payable returns (uint256)",
];
const swapRouter = new ethers.Contract(swapRouterAddress, swapRouterAbi, signer);
const ll=await signer.getAddress()
 const swapTx1 = await swapRouter.exactInputSingle({
        tokenIn: "0x493257fD37EDB34451f62EDf8D2a0C418852bA4C",
         tokenOut: "0x1d17CBcF0D6D143135aE902365D2E5e2A16538D4",
        fee: 500,
      recipient: "Myaddress",
      deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 10,
      amountIn: 10000,
        amountOutMinimum: 0, // Adjust for slippage tolerance
      sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0, // No price limit
      });

